# Pdf viewer in Mac with `fit content'

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, pdf

I am desperately looking for a Pdf viewer which can show the pdf without any margins, that would help me a lot in viewing two pdfs simultaneously.

Thanks.

Comment: could you just resize the pdf viewer window to fit?

Comment: @CML then i will get the page fit to the viewer, but i will still see those margins, which takes up 30% of the page.

Comment: could you crop the pdf margin or is it necessary? if yes see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cropping the page could work for you.

> So, open up whatever PDF you want to crop in Preview. Hit the Select button in the toolbar and crop the first page as you want all the selected pages to be cropped. The cropping tool works just like any crop tool in your average photo editing software. Then, in the sidebar on the right, select a thumbnail of any page (make sure the sidebar is in thumbnail view and not Table of Contents or Annotations view). Now check to be sure that the crop size is what you want to be applied to all the pages you select, then hit Select All, and go to Tools » Crop or hit Command-K.

[Here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=200711012305556) is the link how to crop all pages within a pdf.

Uncrop see [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3461580?start=0&tstart=0)

Answer (score 0):

Preview should do the job just fine.

Comment: How-details would help

Comment: What Andrew said! I'd imagine OP tried Preview already and was unsatisfied with the job it was doing. If you could explain how exactly you can make it do a more satisfactory job, that'd help!

Comment: Hi, there is now fit content option by default which trims the margins automatically, all I can do is zoom which is annoying because i end up moving my pages sideways instead of vertically while scrolling. If you have ever used evince, there is an option of hiding the margins, is there a pdf viewer where such a thing is possible  ?